# JavaScript Gurus -- What is the recommended approach for helper functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop

**JavaScript Gurus,**

What is the recommended approach for helper functions? I would like to choose one technique, and run with it to create my new "class".

Here are the design options I have pondered:

**Option 1: Helper function in outer scope, invoke with context of instance**

```
function createPane (pane) {
    // logic to create pane
    var proto = Object.create(this.paneList);
    $.extend(paneProto, pane);
    return paneProto;
}

Panes.prototype.initialize = function (panes) {
    var _this = this;
    _.each(panes, function () {
        _this.panes.push(createPane.call(_this, this));
    });
}
```

- **Pros:** Simple syntax. `createPane` is not published on the instance.
- **Cons:** `createPane` is accessible in other scopes.

**Option 2: Helper function in closure, invoke with context of instance**

```
Panes.prototype.initialize = (function () {

    function createPane (pane) {
        // same logic as last createPane
    }

    return function (panes) {
        // same logic as before - calls createPane
    }

})();
```

- **Pros:** `createPane` is not published on the instance.
- **Cons:** Lower readability and testability; Testing of this helper must occur in the scope of initialize.

**Option 3: Prepend _ to name to indicate a private method**

```
Panes.prototype._createPane = function (pane) {
    // same logic as last createPane
}

Panes.prototype.initialize = function (panes) {
    // same logic as last, except calls this._createPane
}
```

- **Pros:** Implicit context of `_createPane` is the instance. Testability from the outside.
- **Cons:** Exposing helper function on the instance.

Comment: While I'm interested in the discussion, this question is definitively opinion-based, and will be closed as such (or put [on hold](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/) pending revision). I'm unsure, but [Programmers.se] *might* be a valid home for the discussion (if it's not already there).

Comment: Thanks David -- I will post there

Comment: And please do, participate in the discussion:
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/235555/javascript-gurus-what-is-the-recommended-approach-for-helper-functions-in-jav